# Diatonic Minor Harmonicas?

Tags: harmonica

Played the other night with a harp player who mentioned harps that he had in minor keys. Sadly, never had chance to hear them used.

Since there are different notes involved in minor keys, which would be used? Or is there a choice between melodic and harmonic harmonicas? If it was only natural minor, surely a standard diatonic harp would suffice?

And why do they get to be called harps..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably over 99% of all 10 hole diatonic harmonicas are tuned to a standard tuning, but within the remaining 1% there's a world of variation, and it doesn't even stop at minor and minor!

> If it was only natural minor, surely a standard diatonic harp would suffice?

My short answer to this question would be NO, but let me elaborate. There are several reasons.

One is the very limited set of **chords** on most diatonics - a standard tuned C harp has a large C major cord on all blow notes, a large G7 chord with a D note base in the bottom-half draw, and two three note Dm chords over holes 4-6 and 8-10. For playing something majory in C or G, or blues in G this is fine, but if you want chords for any kind of minor music this is rather boring.

Another is the limited set of **notes** on the standard tuned harp. Even if you learn to bend notes, there are two Eb, two F#, one Bb, one C# and one G# missing in the 3 octave span of the instrument. Now if you want to play in Dm, the only minor key where you have a tonic chord, it doesn't matter if it's natural minor or harmonic minor, as either the missing Bb or the missing C# will cause you trouble. The missing notes can all be produced by advanced playing techniques (called overblows and overdraws) but except for the years of practice they take to master the instrument itself must be finely calibrated way past what you find in a music store.

A third reason to use an alternate tuning is that blows, draws and bends each have a different character; in general draws and bends are considered more expressive. This is another reason D minor is a popular minor key on a C harp, because the notes D, F and A are all bendable draw notes in the middle octave. Even if we use our C harp to play blues in the key of G, the most mainstream thing imaginable, the G in the middle octave is an inexpressive blow note.

Playing the harmonica you are left with two choices: Either you embrace these difficulties and see how you can work around the limitations to shape the music after the instrument, or you shape the instrument after the music and use another tuning that is better suited for what you want to do.

Most harmonica brands offer minor key harps, usually both harmonic and natural minor. You get large minor chords, all the notes you need, and at least with the natural minor harps you get the notes in the tonic chord as expressive draw notes.

Many many pages could be written on various harmonica tunings, but I'll stop here as I think what I've written already answers your question.

Oh, and on your final question, take a look at https://www.patmissin.com/ffaq/q3.html for the history of the word 'harp' :)

Answer (score 1):

> Since there are different notes involved in minor keys, which would be used?

While there are different kinds of harmonicas, "major" and "minor" are modes of the same diatonic scale; same notes. Most harp players use the Mixolydian mode (aka *dominant*). Here are the notes of a diatonic harp in G Major, which would be used to play blues in D Major:

[image]

Since the only note difference between D Mixolydian and D Dorian (often used for "minor Blues") is the 3rd scale degree, a harp player may still use this G harp for a song in "D minor" and simply bend the F# down (or skip it). Another popular option is to use a C Major harp for songs in D minor, as that would allow you to draw D-F-A.

Unless you know them well enough, I would not give any stock to the player's comments about a special "minor key harp." I played the southeastern blues circuit for years and have met many dozens of harp players, and very few had any formal music training. They probably meant to say that they own the harps needed to play over common minor keys.

> is there a choice between melodic and harmonic harmonicas?

There are chromatic harmonicas, but they are overkill for what you're describing.

Comment: My question involved the fact that there are minor scales that are *not* modes of the major scales, therefore do not contain the same diatonic notes. A (harmonic) minor differs from A Aeolian due to its raised leading note of G#.

Comment: Sorry @Tim your OP specifically asks about "diatonic minor" harps, "minor keys," "different notes in minor keys," and "if it was only natural minor" ... You only mentioned the melodic and harmonic variations once and I addressed that at the end of my answer.

Comment: Also, using second position as described here it's easy to bend the D to C# for your harmonic scale leading tone. @Tim

Comment: It's just that I don't think cross harp is what's used for playing minor blues. Maybe that's not the case, though.

Comment: I have a gig next week with a harp player who has a minor harp he bought by mistake. I'll report back after the gig. It does seem, looking at harp sites, that harmonic minor may well be the available one.

Comment: @Tim Awesome to hear. I'd love to learn more about this. Please post a link if you find one. Sorry if I misinterpreted your question, I was merely trying to clarify that the nat. minor and major scales are the same set of notes (although on harp you have to factor the location of said notes blow vs. draw, and which can be bent).